# Resume EIdSocketError connection without restarting the download - Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3

Good day ...

I download a program which generates the error Socket'm using `except on E: EIdSocketError the begin` ... He shows me the error that is generated ... But I would like to address this error ... Because it disconnects with the site I'm downloading, and he for the program, I can not return any download ... unless you close the program and reopen ...

How can I be getting this error, make him try reset a new connection to the site, without me having to restart the program ... So I go back download the latest downloaded file .... because with socket error have to restart the program and return to download the Zero ... 1mb files are small, but they are around 200 for download:

```
on E: EIdSocketError do begin
                     ShowMessage('Socket 2');

                     // +++++------
                     FreeAndNil(fileDownload);
                     fileDownload := TFileStream.Create(local_exe+'media_'+IntToStr(down_num)+'.mp4', fmCreate);
                     IdHTTP.Get(montarURL, fileDownload);
                     Memo1.Lines.Add(formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy',now)+' '+formatdatetime ('hh:mm:ss',now)+' Lista '+IntToStr(numero_tentativa_loop_um)+'. Connection restored.');
                 end;
```

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you have ? Could you include a Delphi version tag into your question ?

Comment: I Have a version Delphi XE3...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Socket Error # 10054 has to correct, because he was the one who appeared ... I do not know if it will work with others:

```
RemoveComponent(IdHTTP);
IdHTTP.Free;
IdHTTP := Nil;
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
```

ATT MT

Comment: You do NOT need to destroy and recreate the `TIdHTTP` object to recover from a socket error.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. It is a hack workaround, not a solution.  And it does not address the issue of resuming a download where it left off instead of starting over from the beginning.

Comment: Why ask for help, and then when you get it from the undisputed Stack Overflow Indy expert, an Indy developer no less, you ignore it? How can you learn if you think you know everything already? If you think that, why even ask?

Answer (score 5):

`EIdSocketError` means exactly what its name says - a socket error occurred.  Without seeing the actual socket error code involved, typically all you can do to recovery is just `Disconnect()` the socket, `Clear` the `IOHandler.InputBuffer`, and re-`Connect()` and resume your download where you left off (if possible) or re-start the download from the beginning again.

For HTTP, you can resume a download if the resource being downloaded accepts a `Range: bytes=...` request header (see the `TIdHTTP.Request.Range` property), such as if it reported an `Accept-Ranges: bytes` response header (see the `TIdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges` property) in an earlier download attempt.  See [RFC 2616 Section 14.35](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) for more details.

**Update**: For example:

```
try
  IdHTTP.Get(montarURL, fileDownload);
except
  on E: EIdSocketError do begin
    IdHTTP.Disconnect;
    if IdHTTP.IOHandler <> nil then IdHTTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    ...
    if IdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges = 'bytes' then begin
      IdHTTP.Request.Range := IntToStr(fileDownload.Size) + '-';
    end else begin
      fileDownload.Size := 0;
    end;
    IdHTTP.Get(montarURL, fileDownload);
    ...
  end;
end;
```